# Keyboard Shortcuts to switch directly to applications

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, application-switcher

Using Unity is there a way to create a single key shortcut to switch to an existing instance of an application?  For instance, rather than hitting alt-tab N times to switch to my browser I could simply hit F1, for a terminal I could hit F2.

The run-one solution in another question doesn't work as it launches a new instance.  The Launcher itself comes close as it allows me to use Super-[0-9] for pinned applications.  This would be sufficient if I could remap the launcher shortcuts to be single keys.
Perhaps there is a dbus message that could be send from a script and the script could be tied to a custom shortcut?  A simpler solution would be great too.

Comment: In two-keys case `super+A` does it .

Comment: Have you tried adding your desired action/command key to: "System Settings" > Keyboard > Shortcuts?

Comment: Both of those open a new instance/window rather than switching to the existing one.  Your comments have given me the idea to try using xdotool to simulate the presses.

Answer (score 2):

An ugly solution is to use xdotool to simulate the Super-[1-9] keypress.  The xdotool command sequence can then be mapped to a custom keyboard shortcut from  "System Settings" > Keyboard > Shortcuts".  The commands to be run for the shortcuts are

Super-1

```
sh -c 'echo "keydown super sleep 0.2 key 1 super" | xdotool -'
```

Super-2

```
sh -c 'echo "keydown super sleep 0.2 key 2 super" | xdotool -'
```

Super-3

```
sh -c 'echo "keydown super sleep 0.2 key 3 super" | xdotool -'
```

Comment: This is cool solution thank you. Unfortunately I couldn't manage to simulate a shift+super+key with xdotool in order to force a new instance of an app instead of switching to it. Can you please help me out on this?

Comment: This seems to work for me with chrome in the first position.  `sh -c 'echo "keydown super keydown shift sleep 0.2 key 1 super keyup shift" | xdotool -'` @aleprovencio

Answer (score 1):

I use [AutoKey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) to map keys for switching to Terminal. A short demo is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMtbkCVmwGY). It's very easy to use.